# How can I order a Map properly?

Tags: java, list, comparator

So I was trying to order a `Map`, and I learned that there is a thing in `java` called `Comparator` that helps me do it, but for some reason it appears to have no error but the program doesn't work... It's appears to have an infinite cicle but I don't know where.

```
public long[] top_most_active (TCD_community com, int N){
    int i=0;
    long[] array= new long[N];
    Arrays.fill (array,0);

    List<User> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l = topX (N, com);

    for (User u : l) {
        array[i] = u.getid();
        System.out.println (u.getid());
        i++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

I want to order everything and pick up to my list the `top N users` with most posts!

```
public List<User> topX(int x , TCD_community com) {
    List<User> l = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, User> m = com.getUsers(); 
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, User> entrada : m.entrySet()) {
        User u = entrada.getValue();
        l.add(u);
        l.sort(new Comparator<User>() {
            public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
                if(u1.getpost_count() == u2.getpost_count()){
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (u1.getpost_count() > u2.getpost_count())
                    return -1;
                else return 1;
            }
        });
    }
    return l.subList(0,x);
}
```

Comment: How does `TCD_community` (Java naming conventions would have you write `TcdCommunity` or `TCDCommunity` in camel case) implement `getUsers()`? If the backing `Map` is a `HashMap`, there is no order.

Comment: @ifly6 my class implements `TCD_community`, and `getUsers()` is defined at `TCD_community`!! Also `TCD_community` is using `Map` but they are `HashMaps` yes, but I want to order the users basically so it shouldn't affect being a `HashMap` because it can be done!

Comment: HashMaps don't have order because of how hashes work

Comment: @ifly6 yes but I'm ordering the `List`, not the `HashMap`!! I just use the `HashMap` to get my users and see if they come first or second comparing to another and put that on the `List`.

Comment: @Bruno then ask how to order a list, not a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to sort your list after adding each entry to the list.

You should simply collect all the users into a new list, and afterwards sort the list.

```
List<User> l = new ArrayList<>(com.getUsers().values());
l.sort( ... your comparator ...);
return l.subList(0, x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicated things. Consider the following:

The `top_most_active` method becomes:

```
public long[] top_most_active (TCD_community com, int N){
       long[] result = topX(N, com).stream()
                                   .mapToLong(User::getId)
                                   .peek(id -> System.out.println(id))
                                   .toArray();
}
```

then the `topX` method becomes:

```
public List<User> topX(int x , TCD_community com) {
    return com.getUsers() 
              .stream()
              .map(e -> e.getValue())
              .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(User::getpost_count).reversed())
              .limit(x)
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

This fixes the issue of you trying to sort the accumulating list in each iteration of the loop as well as removing most of the redundancy and boilerplate code you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it seems you don't want to order a *Map*, you want to order a list.

What I think your code does now is a number of things: (1) It deals with a Map for some reason. I guess it's like Python `enumerate(your_list)` giving your indices, but that's unnecessary. (2) It also seemingly re-sorts the list at every single add. You don't need to do that.

Simply get all your elements and sort them later in one go. Getting things is a relatively simple task. Comparing and ordering them is relatively expensive, so you want to minimise the times you have to do that.

However it is, to order your list, just implement `Comparator` and invoke a sorting method with it. Doing this is easy now, since we have both natural order in `int` (and `Integer`, `long`, `Long`, etc.) and easy comparator creation via `Comparator#comparing`.

Get your list of users. Then,

```
Map<Integer, User> map = magicSupplier();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
Comparator<User> comparator = Comparator.comparing(User::postCount)
Collections.sort(users, comparator.reversed()); // for most-to-least
```

With the assumption that your `User` object has a method `postCount` returning a naturally ordered integer or `long` that counts the number of posts. I think you call it something different.

Then do your sublisting and return.